# How to remove ➜ ~ from Terminal

Tags: terminal, mac

Earlier, I had installed Anaconda and a bit after that, it showed this with (base) in front of it. I searched up how to remove base and followed those steps, but I'm still left with this. How do I revert my terminal to the original setting?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have OMZ installed?

Comment: I'm not sure if I do

Comment: What version macOS and what shell?  To get the latter, type `echo $0`. And to be certain, you didn’t install Oh-My-Zsh shell add-in?

Comment: If I have the oh-my-zsh.sh file then is it installed?

Comment: Yes.  You have OMZ

Comment: I am using Ventura 13.2.1 and it is using -zsh

Comment: Find where the variable `PS1` is set and you can modify it so it has the prompt you want. It could be `.zprofile` or `.zshrc`. I also [discourage the use of OMZ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/455221/119271) for practical reasons.

Comment: Where would I find that variable?

Comment: I had to edit the comment as I fat fingered “Return” on the iPad screen keyboard.  See above

Comment: I did not see the variable in those files

Comment: Do I need to uninstall OMZ?

Comment: My advise is to start there.  If you want a colorful Prompt, we can assist you with that

Comment: Ok, that fixed the problem, thank you!

Comment: I’ll type up an answer for you for future reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this!